# Elasticsearch nested doc with AND condition

Tags: elasticsearch

The ES scheme we model a student document which contains multiple nested courses documents. I want to search for students who has course X and Y.

Mapping:

```
{
  "index_classroom": {
    "mappings": {
      "content": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
          "courses": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "grade": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
       } 
     }
    }
   }
```

Sample docs:

```
{
    "_index": "index_classroom",
    "_type": "content",
    "_id": "6170_130",
    "_score": 0.72833073,
    "_source": {
      "courses": [
        {
          "name": "maths",
          "grade": "A" 
        },
        {
          "name": "economics",
          "grade": "A+"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want to query all students who have taken Math and Economics (further to add is "and not Biology".)

Thanks!

Comment: I am using elastic 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "courses",
                        "query": { 
                            "match": {
                                "courses.name": "economics"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "courses",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "courses.name": "maths"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "courses",
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "courses.name": "Biology"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```